# Spline normal in a given point

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, normals, cubic-spline

I've used the code avaiable at this link to implement the Cubic Spline Interpolation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560163/Csharp-Cubic-Spline-Interpolation

For each point in the spline I need to find the spline normal at that point.
Does anyone known how to get the normal at the spline at a given point P(x_0,y_0)?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For a parametric equation, `X=f(t), Y=g(t)`, the direction of the tangent vector is given by `(f'(t), g'(t))`, and that of the normal vector is orthogonal `(-g'(t), f'(t))`. The article shows you how to compute the slope, i.e. the derivative.

Comment: Ok for the formula, but I'm asking how to calculate the normal from that code, not the slope but the vector. Thank you

Comment: Hem, it's in front of your eyes.